# Получить строку, представляющую выражение, используемое как аргумент функции в С#

Tags: c#, макросы

В языках C/C++ можно создать макрос, использующий строковое представление аргумента.

```
#define str(arg) #arg
...
str(5 + 5) => "5 + 5"
str("AB") => "\"AB\""
```

Такой механизм часто используется в assert'ах или при логировании.

Как в C# добиться подобного результата?

***PS**: видел решение через `System.Linq.Expressions`, но оно не подходит так как могут создаться замыкания и при фактическом вызове лямбды может получится не тот результат, который ожидался в момент вызова основного метода*

Comment: К счастью, писать макросы с аргументами в C# нельзя. А можно подробнее о том, что хочется получить?

Answer (score 0):

Данная возможность появится в одной из следующих версий C# 8.x в виде атрибута [`CallerArgumentExpression`](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/c-sharp-8-x-next/).

Будет это выглядеть следующим образом:

```
public static void NotNull < T > (T argument,  
    [CallerArgumentExpression("argument")] string argumentExpression = null)  
where T: class
{  
    if (argument == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(paramName: argumentExpression);  
}
/* ... */
// CallerArgumentExpression: convert the expressions to a string!    
Verify.NotNull(array); // paramName: "array"
```